# Anyway to get a fullscreen background clickable even with div's on top of it?

Tags: css, fullscreen

I am trying a fullscreen background which must be clickable. So far i got this going.
But now i have put some div's on top of the background and the background isn't clickable just the part not covered by div's works.

Here is my stripped source

```
<div id="page-background"><img src....</div><div id="wrapper">here bunch of div's</div>
```

here's my css
`html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}#page-background {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}#wrapper {position:relative; z-index:1; padding:10px;}`

Comment: try position: absolute on the page-background

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery live() method which supports click event propagation: http://api.jquery.com/live/#typefn

Answer (score 0):

Also, here's a nice article about event bubbling, maybe that helps as well:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html